# Pipe pipewire to ffmpeg stdin

Tags: ffmpeg, pipeline, stdin

I want to take audio from pipewire and send it to the stdin of ffmpeg via it's use of command line pipes. Is there a way to get audio from pipewire to something like a cat command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg can run as a jack or pulse client, so the way forward is to treat pipewire as it if were one of those two things.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#jack